# Chapter Number only unbold in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I have created `toc` and how do unbold the `chapter number` in table of contents. The `dotsep` between chapter title and page number is also disapper? How do on the `dotsep`. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@dotsep{2}
\newcommand*\l@fmchapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip0em% \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{2pc}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -33pt
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi\vskip1pt}

\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 5pt \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss \normalfont #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\newcommand*\l@bmchapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip11pt% \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{2pc}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \fontsize{10}{13}
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -35.6pt
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi\vskip-11pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Contents}

\contentsline {fmchapter}{\numberline {}About the Author}{ix}
\contentsline {fmchapter}{\numberline {}Acknowledgements}{xi}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Sequential Assignment}{11}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}Revenue Maximization}{41}
\contentsline {bmchapter}{\numberline {}Bibliography}{181}
\contentsline {bmchapter}{\numberline {}Index}{191}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package. Perhaps you can fix your TOC with that.

Comment: @Aradnix: I would like to adjust in `LaTeX Macro` only and not like to add any additional package.

Comment: Why don't you use simply `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: I have tried the command `tableofcontents` and also the `chapter number` is coming in `bold`. But i have no need `chapter number` is bold.

Comment: Please drop the outdated `times` package. Use `mathptmx` instead.

Comment: @Christian: `times` is changed to `mathptmx`.

Comment: @Balaji: I see, well I forgot to write, that will not solve your problem with the TOC. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `normalfont` within `numberline`.

A less manual approach using `tocstyle` or `tocloft` is recommendend, though.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@dotsep{2}
\newcommand*\l@fmchapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip0em% \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{2pc}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -33pt
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi\vskip1pt}

\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 5pt \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss \normalfont #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\newcommand*\l@bmchapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip11pt% \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{2pc}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \fontsize{10}{13}
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -35.6pt
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi\vskip-11pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Contents}

\contentsline {fmchapter}{\numberline {}About the Author}{ix}
\contentsline {fmchapter}{\numberline {}Acknowledgements}{xi}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {\normalfont 1}Introduction}{1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {\normalfont 2}Sequential Assignment}{11}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {\normalfont 3}Revenue Maximization}{41}
\contentsline {bmchapter}{\numberline {}Bibliography}{181}
\contentsline {bmchapter}{\numberline {}Index}{191}
\end{document}
```